# How to change python3 version on a mac machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed different version of python3 on my machine

If I digit

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

while If I digit

brew list python python3

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/2to3
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/2to3-3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/easy_install-3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/idle3
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/idle3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/pip3
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/pip3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/pydoc3
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/pydoc3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/python3.9-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin/wheel3
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (3095 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/IDLE 3.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/lib/pkgconfig/ (4 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/libexec/bin/ (7 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/libexec/pip/ (480 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/libexec/setuptools/ (334 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/libexec/wheel/ (44 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Python Launcher 3.app/Contents/ (16 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/share/man/ (2 files)
```

and If I digit

```
pip3 --version
pip 20.3.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

How can I set everything to `python3.8`

Comment: What does `which python3` show? Have you considered using `pyenv` rather than `brew` for managing Python versions?

Comment: If I digit `which python3` I get `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: And  does `ls -l /usr/bin/python3` show a symlink to somewhere else? If not you need to modify `$PATH` to put your `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/bin` folder before `/usr/bin`

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac